# Is it possible to generalize or simplify the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm stuck in a calculation using SQL Server because the formula that is used to compute the column is as follows:

First term: $t_{0} \times i_{0} \times j_{0} \times k_{0}$

Second term: $(t_{0} \times i_{0} \times j_{0} \times k_{0}) \times (1 - i_{0}) / i_{0} \times (t_{1} \times i_{1} \times j_{1} \times k_{1})$

Third term: $((t_{0} \times i_{0} \times j_{0} \times k_{0}) \times (1 - i_{0}) / i_{0} \times (t_{1} \times i_{1} \times j_{1} \times k_{1})) \times (1 - i_{1}) / i_{1} \times (t_{2} \times i_{2} \times j_{2} \times k_{2})$

Basicaly each term uses the previous term, then adds $(1 - i_{n-1}) / i_{n-1} \times (t_{n} \times i_{n} \times j_{n} \times k_{n})$

Where $n$ is the period starting with $0$.

Please, let me now if I can improve my question somehow.

Thank you, guys!

Comment: Without values/formulas for $t_n$, $i_n$, $j_n$, or $k_n$, I don't think there's any possible simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variables are all simply numbers and the operation is normal multiplication, note that the third term (corresponding to $n=2$), for example, can be rewritten as

$$t_0(1-i_0)j_0k_0t_1(1-i_1)j_1k_1t_2i_2j_2k_2$$

which can, provided $i_2\not=1$, be written as

$${i_2\over1-i_2}t_0(1-i_0)j_0k_0t_1(1-i_1)j_1k_1t_2(1-i_2)j_2k_2$$

In general, the $n$th term is expressible as

$${i_n\over1-i_n}\prod_{m=0}^nt_m(1-i_m)j_mk_m$$

if $i_n\not=1$.  It you need to allow the possibility of $i_n=1$, the formula is better written as

$$t_ni_nj_nk_n\prod_{m=0}^{n-1}t_m(1-i_m)j_mk_m$$

Remark: The formulation of the problem implies that $i_m\not=0$ is assumed for all $m$.